# Angular-UI & Bootstrap: change class based on class

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Angular-UI and Bootstrap 3.

I have this HTML connected to a scope (assume the scope has a $scope.myBtn = "A", say).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="myBtn" btn-radio="A">A</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="myBtn" btn-radio="B">B</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="myBtn" btn-radio="C">C</button>
```

This produces three blue buttons, which is what I want.  When one of the buttons is clicked, the $scope.myBtn value gets set to the right value (say, "B") and that button's class gets set to:

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary active" ng-model="myBtn" btn-radio="B">B</button>
```

(notice the addition of **active** in the class).

When one button is **active** I want to *remove* the "btn-primary" class and *add* the "btn-success" class.  I know I could do it this way (and it is what I am actually using now):

```
<button
  type      = "button"
  class     = "btn"
  ng-class  = "{
    'btn-primary': myBtn != 'B',
    'btn-success': myBtn == 'B'
  }"
  ng-model  = "myBtn"
  btn-radio = "'B'">B</button>
```

But that seems brutally verbose for *every* button...  Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a directive to conditionally set the class by observing the model value

```
app.directive('myClass', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngModel', function (item) {
                if (scope.myBtn !== 'B') {
                    attrs.$set('class', "btn-primary");
                } else {
                    attrs.$set('class', "btn-success");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GZnem/)**</kbd>